# Program Received signal EXC_BAD_SIGNAL in main.m while appending data to the groupped tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  for (int i=0; i<[rowsarray count]; i++) {
    [mutabledict setObject:[rowsarray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[datearray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"mutable dict is :::%@",mutabledict);
}

NSLog(@"temp value is:::%@",mutabledict);
self.tableContents =mutabledict;
[mutabledict release];
NSLog(@"table %@",self.tableContents);
NSLog(@"table with Keys %@",[self.tableContents allKeys]);
self.sortedKeys =[[self.tableContents allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog(@"sorted %@",self.sortedKeys);
//  [tableContents release];
[sortedKeys release];
[rowsarray release];
[datearray release];

  }
```

mutabledict is a NsMutableDictionary,rowsarray is a array of objects and datearray is a array of keys.This code displays correctly but I am trying to add the data to the tableview then the control is going to main.m with error.Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `sortedArrayUsingSelector`: this returns an autoreleased object, so probably you're getting this error when you call `[sortedKeys release];`(so remove it).
If `self.sortedKeys` is the array you want to display on the table view make sure to add `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in the header of your `UIViewController` and implements the required callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for respondng I remove the [sortedKeys release]but again I got the exception as Program Received signal "SIGABRT" in - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}Please give  me suggestion

Comment: Please, post your callbacks too, and tell us in which line the program stops

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:[self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
return [listData count];
}

Comment: -[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b26a30
this is the error I got

Comment: it seems that listData is a string not an array, so please try to NSLog listData to know what is it..probably you're accessing to the wrong entry in the dictionary.

Comment: list data is :::cab is printed correctly then where is the problem.Please tell me

Comment: :::cab is a string, right? You have to return an integer not a string. The problem is that you're calling `count` on a string, this method doesn't exist for strings. How many sections/rows do you want?

Comment: yeah cab is string.The sections/rows comming from database dynamically that is multiple rows data not fixed data

Comment: That should not be a string, it must be an array or a dictionary that represents your sections, the same goes for rows. Controls well the structure of the your dictionary, you're really close. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah that is NSArray represented in 2nd comment.then how to add the nsmutabledictionary of objects and keys to the NSArray.plz tell me.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad or just try by `return [self.tableContents count];`

Comment: Hi Mat Thanks for ur replay but the same exception comes can u tell me is it because of Memory leaks or any thing.